# Material UI: how to make buttons padding uniform size?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I have a series of Material UI buttons as such:

```
      <Button className={classes.button}>Edit</Button>
      <Button className={classes.button}>Duplicate</Button>
      <hr />
      <Button className={classes.button} color="secondary">
        Remove
      </Button>
```

I've given them a class that simply displays them as `block` eg:

```
  button: {
    display: 'block',
  },
```

They work fine but there seems to be a setting where the smaller `Edit` button has extra padding on it because it has less text in the name:

[image]

If I add more text it corrects it:

[image]

Would anyone know how to fix this? If there is a setting somewhere?

Comment: From where you're getting Button component? Is it from material-ui?

Comment: Share your code in sand box please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the min-width property which forces that "padding". Try just adding `min-width: 'unset'` to your button class.

There is a live example
https://codesandbox.io/embed/naughty-galois-bc0sz?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark